# Torrent websites going underground?

Tags: security, bittorrent, utorrent

**Request** I, don't know i should ask it or not.But it concerns with the privacy and safety of pc.Still  if anyone finds it wrong just tell me in the comment and i will delete it right away.

**Question** After the fall of kickass torrent, Many other torrent websites have started to go underground. I don't know what it exactly means but when you go to their page .It is  a message appears
Due to hard regulations & security issues for bittorrent users, this torrnt website has moved into a more secure and even faster district of the internet!
If you want to get our newest Torrent , you are welcome to join our free community! 
**All you have to do is downloading this client**, install it and enter a valid mail adress,free mails like gmail work fine.
You will then receive your free login information instantly.

I want to know How much it is safe to download the client.This torrent website is very old and well known . The website is **Demonoid** and **Extratorrent**

Comment: I would not install such a thing unless I clearly understood what it is. it sounds quite suspicious. Reasearch it online and you will likely find information on what the software is, an whether it is safe. for now there is no way for us to tell you, without knowing more about the situation.

Comment: @FrankThomas If i tell you the name of website.{if it is right here to do that}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is normal that they increase security, it sounds suspicious. You should contact the owners of each and ask for details. It's suspect if more did this on the same time. The site may have been compromised.

For a tracker, it's sufficient for it to go private (invite-only system from internal members already there).

-Update-
The current demoniod site's location is dot PW and it's open registration and does not require anything to work. So you're most likely on a scam site.

ET was shutdown in March 2017, so any client thing from there is a scam.

Comment: please tell me i should install it or not?

Comment: Not until you talk directly with tracker's owners.

Comment: I have wrote the website name

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks brother, you just saved me. May I ask you a few more questions? Do you have a chat room?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69370/borg

Answer (score 1):

> You will then receive your free login information instantly.

Sending passwords in plain text is a pitfall. I would not be surprised if this proves to be a spam-related honeypot that collects valid (notice the emphasis on it in your post) email addresses for spammers.

Comment: how  much it is safe to install that client

Comment: @Kislay Tripathi - its not safe.  An untrusted binary from an untrusted source promoting itself as getting you stuff you should not have access to is suspect.  The way its being communicated should ring loud sirens (forget alarm bells)